# Tensor product of group algebras

Tags: group-theory, commutative-algebra, abelian-groups, group-rings

Let $G,G_1$ and $G_2$ are three abelian groups with group homomorphisms $\phi_i:G\to G_i$. This gives $k$-algebra homomorphisms $k[\phi_i]:k[G]\to k[G_i]$. So we can consider $k[G_i]'s$ as $k[G]$-module via the homomorphisms $k[\phi_i]$. We can consider the tensor product $k[G_1]\otimes_{k[G]}k[G_2]$ and this will be again $k$-algebras.

My question is there a simpler way to describe the $k$-algebra: $k[G_1]\otimes_{k[G]}k[G_2]$?

For example take $G=\{e\}$, the identity group; then $k[G]=k$ and hence $$k[G_1]\otimes_{k[G]}k[G_2]=k[G_1]\otimes_kk[G_2]\cong k[G_1\times G_2].$$

So I was wondering if there exists any simpler way to express $k[G_1]\otimes_{k[G]}k[G_2]$ like above.

Note that here the groups are abelian and hence the group algebras are commutative rings. Therefore the tensor product makes sense.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Simpler way? In your example, yes. Generally, not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's just the group algebra of the pushout of $G_1$ and $G_2$ over $G$ (explicitly, the quotient of $G_1\oplus G_2$ by the image of $(\phi_1,-\phi_2):G\to G_1\oplus G_2$).  This follows immediately from the fact that the group algebra functor from abelian groups to commutative $k$-algebras is left adjoint to the multiplicative group functor, and thus preserves colimits, so it turns the pushout of $G_1$ and $G_2$ over $G$ into the pushout of $k[G_1]$ and $k[G_2]$ over $k[G]$ which is just the tensor product.

Comment: Can please give me some references related to these things?